# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los resultados de una consulta de neo4j parametrizada en mi aplicación?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, neo4j

primeramente agradezco cualquier ayuda. Necesito mostrar en una aplicación web el resultado de una consulta parametrizada a una base de datos de Neo4j. Necesito obtener estos resultados (adjunto imagen)
[[image: Datos a obtener1]

Este es el código donde se supone que hago la consulta a la base de datos

```
app.get('/consulta5',function(req, res){
session
    .run('MATCH(p:proyecto) RETURN p.poblacionMeta, COUNT(p.nombre)')
    .then(function(resultConsult){
        var proyctArr = [];
        resultConsult.records.forEach(function(record){
            console.log(record);
            proyctArr.push({
                poblacionMeta: record._fields[0].properties.poblacionMeta,
                nombre: record._fields[0].properties.nombre
            });
        });
        res.render('consulta5',{
            proycts: proyctArr
        });
}) 
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

});

Este es el error que me lanza:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'poblacionMeta' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe cambiar app.get por app.post. De igual forma hacer ese cambio el la view donde se despliegue el resultado de la consulta

Answer (score 0):

El error es un tanto ambiguo, ya que dice que no puede leer el valor de `poblacionMeta` en `record._fields[0].properties.poblacionMeta`, por lo que o bien no se esta conectando a la db, y por eso devuelve algun tipo de error (404, 403, o hasta un 200 empty etc) por eso tu variable esta no definida al momento de querer sacarla del record.

- podrias hacer una prueba con fiddler o postman para ver como te
  regresa la respuesta neo4j.
- Una vez que compruebes que si conecta y si regresa respuesta, entonces solo es cuestión de ajustar tu método en front.